# Retrieving data from Firebase Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Structure of my Firebase Datebase looks like that:

[image]

I want to retrieve data from it in such a manner that when I change the value of the "Name" in database it will instantly change in Android Studio. Right now, I use `.addChildEventListner` method combined with `Map<String, String>`. Could someone help me ?

Edit: My code:

```
   Firebase markerRef = myFirebaseRef.child("marker");

    markerRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(map.get("Lat"));
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(map.get("Lon"));
            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            String filename = map.get("Name");
            String[] splitString = filename.split(",");


            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(location)
                    .title(splitString[0])
                    .snippet(splitString[1])
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: show the code, we can't help you without it

Comment: @DimaRostopira I added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your activity create empty HashMap
`Hasmap<String, Marker> markers = new Hashmap<>();`
Then in `onChildAdded`

```
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(location)
                        .title(splitString[0])
                        .snippet(splitString[1])
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
markers.add.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), m);
```

And in `onChildChanged`

```
Marker m = markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
m.setPosition(newLocation);
//And anything else, that changing
```

And finally in onChildRemoved

```
markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey()).remove();
markers.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
```

Comment: @Michal thanks for accepting, I finally can set bounty for my question :D

Answer (score 1):

Firebase data is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to a FirebaseDatabase reference. The listener is triggered once for the initial state of the data and again anytime the data changes.

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

To add a value event listener, use the addValueEventListener() or addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method. To add a child event listener, use the addChildEventListener() method.

You can use the onDataChange() method to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event. This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing all data at that location, including child data. If there is no data, the snapshot returned is null.

Example :-

```
 ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    // ...
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
 }
 };
 mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Child events are triggered in response to specific operations that happen to the children of a node from an operation such as a new child added through the push() method or a child being updated through the updateChildren() method. Each of these together can be useful for listening to changes to a specific node in a database.

Example :-

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String     previousChildName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

    // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
    Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);

    // ...
 }

 @Override
 public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

    // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
    // comment and if so displayed the changed comment.
    Comment newComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

    // ...
 }

 @Override
 public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

    // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
    // comment and if so remove it.
    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

    // ...
}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

    // A comment has changed position, use the key to determine if we are
    // displaying this comment and if so move it.
    Comment movedComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load comments.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
};
ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method to simplify this scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again.

This is useful for data that only needs to be loaded once and isn't expected to change frequently or require active listening. For instance,

Example:-

```
final String userId = getUid();
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get user value
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```